# How to get DbContext Instance within UnitOfWork via Ninject?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ninject, unit-of-work, ninject.web.mvc

I Use UnitOfWork Pattern with Entity Framework to expose DbContext using bellow code. So My question is that, is it poosible to get Context instance with Ninject ?

**IUnitOfWork**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<C> :  IDisposable
{
        int Commit();
        C GetContext { get; set; }
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork<C> : IUnitOfWork<C> where C : DbContext
    {
        private bool _disposed;
        private readonly C _dbContext = null;

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            GetContext = _dbContext ?? Activator.CreateInstance<C>();
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            return GetContext.SaveChanges();
        }


        public C GetContext
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
[...]
```

Now within **NinjectWebCommon**

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();
  kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>();
}
```

Without using `_dbContext ?? Activator.CreateInstance<C>();` , can it be possible to get **DbContext** instance via **Ninject** ?

Comment: Have you tried constructor injection?

Comment: `kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();` I can do that ? but what will be the code within UnitOfWork ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ninject, but I would assume you could add a constructor that accepts a `C` parameter: `public UnitOfWork(C context)`.

Comment: @jrummell: Yes right you are. `private readonly C _dbcontext;

        public UnitOfWork(C dbcontext)
        {
            _dbcontext = dbcontext;
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible . check the solution bellow

**Ninject DI Configuration**

```
kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>();
kernel.Bind<IEmployeeRepository>().To<EmployeeRepository>();
```

And within **UnitOfWork**

```
   public class UnitOfWork<C> : IUnitOfWork<C> where C : DbContext
    {
        private readonly C _dbcontext;

        public UnitOfWork(C dbcontext)
        {
            _dbcontext = dbcontext;
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
           return _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public C GetContext
        {
            get
            {
                return _dbcontext;
            }

        }
[...]
```